# VCR record HTTP interactions with webmock create .yml without values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ethereum

I am doing HTTP interaction with Ganache - ethereum testnet. Ganache url
: http://127.0.0.1:7545. I connect to its by ethereum.rb gem, which using I think Net::HTTP lib:
[class from ethereum.rb gem which establishes connect to ethereum net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BHOC.png)
spec/support/vcr_setup.rb:

```
require 'vcr'
# spec/support/vcr_setup.rb
VCR.configure do |c|
  #the directory where your cassettes will be saved
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr'
  c.stub_with :webmock
end
```

spec/support/webmock.rb:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
# spec/support/webmock.rb
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

my rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ::EthereumApi::Rpc do
  it '#.client' do
    VCR.use_cassette 'public_blockchain/rpc/client' do

      client = ::Ethereum::HttpClient.new('http://127.0.0.1:7545')
      first = client.eth_accounts['result'][0]

      expect(first).to eql('0xd1d2982db68fe27216c86c2a03fc4ef136ff8ce2')
    end
  end
end
```

And as the result a get .yml file with keys but without values:

[.yml without values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BHOC.png)
spec/vcr/some_folder/my_test.yml: